# glibc corrupted double linked list error while running a C code on 64 bit machine

Tags: c, linked-list, 64-bit, glibc, memory-corruption

I have a large C code that works fine on 32 bit machine but fails on 64 bit machines with

`*** glibc detected *** ./XXX.exe: corrupted double-linked list:` error.

I have run Valgrind and have used print statements to exactly pinpoint where the error is coming from but am clueless about the fix. 
The actual code is very big but I am giving the relevant portions here. Hoping someone can help me troubleshoot it.
The actual error is coming from the `Buf_Close()` module where it tries to free `Buf_elm_p p` as `if (p != NULL) free(p);`

These are functions that the main code calls and I am only giving this here as the error is somewhere here. The calling sequence from the main code is:

`1. Buf_Init
2. Buf_New_p
3. Buf_Close`

```
Buf_bf_p 
Buf_Init( size_t elm_size, 
      int    nelm_buf, 
      long   nbuf )
/*******************************************************************************
!C
!Description: Buf_Init (buffer initialize) initializes buffer data structures 
 and buffers.

!Input Parameters:
 elm_size   element size (bytes)
 nelm_buf   number of elements per buffer
 nbuf       number of buffers

!Output Parameters:
 (returns)      pointer to the buffer data structure 
                or NULL for an error return
*****************************************************************************/
{
  Buf_bf_p bf;
  long buf_size;
  long ibuf;

  /* Calculate buffer size and check */
  buf_size = ((long) elm_size) * nelm_buf;

  /*Allocate the buffer data structure */
  if ((bf = (Buf_bf_p) malloc(sizeof(Buf_bf_t))) == NULL)
    {Buf_Error(&BUF_NOMEMORY, "Init");  return NULL;}
  bf->key = BUF_KEY;
  bf->elm_size = elm_size;
  bf->nelm_buf = nelm_buf;
  bf->nbuf = nbuf;
  bf->buf_size = buf_size;
  bf->fp = NULL;
  bf->access = NO_FILE;
  bf->nbuf_alloc = 1;
  bf->ibuf_end = 0;
  bf->ibuf_newest = 0;
  bf->ibuf_oldest = 0;
  bf->nelm = 0;

  /* Allocate the buffer status data structure */
  bf->nbstat = max(NBSTAT_START, bf->nbuf + 1);
  if ((bf->bstat = (Buf_bstat_t *) 
     malloc(bf->nbstat * sizeof(Buf_bstat_t))) == NULL)
    {Buf_Error(&BUF_NOMEMORY, "Init");  return NULL;}

  /* Allocate the first buffer */
  bf->bstat[0].loc = MEM_ONLY;
  if( (bf->bstat[0].buf_p = (Buf_elm_p) malloc(bf->buf_size)) == NULL)
  { Buf_Error(&BUF_NOMEMORY, "Init");  
    return NULL;
  }
  else
  {
     /* initialize */
     memset( bf->bstat[0].buf_p, '\0', bf->buf_size ); 
  }

  bf->bstat[0].newer = -1;
  bf->bstat[0].older = -1;

  /* Initialize the rest of the buffer status array */
  printf("bf->nbstat %d\n", bf->nbstat);
  for (ibuf = 1; ibuf < bf->nbstat; ibuf++) {
    bf->bstat[ibuf].loc = NOT_ALLOC;
    bf->bstat[ibuf].buf_p = NULL;
    bf->bstat[ibuf].newer = -1;
    bf->bstat[ibuf].older = -1;
    bf->bstat[ibuf].initialized = 1;
  }

  return bf;
}

Buf_elm_p 
Buf_New_p( Buf_bf_p bf, 
           long *ielm )
/*******************************************************************************
!C
!Description: Buf_New_p (new buffer element pointer) returns a memory 
 location and element number of a new element; elements are number
 sequentially as they are allocated.

!Input Parameters:
 bf     pointer to the buffer data structure 

!Output Parameters:
 ielm       new element number
 (returns)      pointer to memory location of new element 
                or NULL for error
!Notes:
   1. 'Buf_Init' must be called before this routine to initialize 
      the buffer data structure.
   2. If there is no more space in memory and disk write access is allowed, 
      the oldest buffer is written to disk and the memory is re-used.
   3. If the file is opened with 'read only' access this routine will return 
      an error.

!END
******************************************************************************/
{
  long ibuf, jelm, jbuf, kbuf;
  long nbuf_cmplt;
  Buf_elm_p p;
  long dsk_loc, eof_loc;


  /* New element number/location */
  *ielm = bf->nelm++;
  ibuf = *ielm / bf->nelm_buf;
  jelm = *ielm % bf->nelm_buf;

  /* Are we at the past the end of the last buffer? */
  if (ibuf > bf->ibuf_end) {

    if (ibuf != (bf->ibuf_end + 1))
      {Buf_Error(&BUF_BADBUF, "New_p");  return NULL;}

    /* Re-allocate buffer status data structure if not large enough */
    if( ibuf >= bf->nbstat ) 
    {
       bf->nbstat += min(bf->nbstat, MAX_NEW_NBSTAT);
       if( (bf->bstat = realloc(bf->bstat, bf->nbstat * sizeof(Buf_bstat_t))) 
           == NULL)
      {  Buf_Error(&BUF_NOMEMORY, "New_p");  
          return NULL;
      }
    }

    if (bf->nbuf_alloc < bf->nbuf  ||  bf->access == NO_FILE) {

      /* Allocate a new buffer */
      if( (p = (Buf_elm_p) malloc(bf->buf_size)) == NULL)
      {  Buf_Error(&BUF_NOMEMORY, "New_p");  
         return NULL;
      }
      else
      {
         /* initialize */
         memset( p, '\0', bf->buf_size ); 
      }
      bf->nbuf_alloc++;
      if (bf->nbuf < bf->nbuf_alloc) bf->nbuf = bf->nbuf_alloc;

    } else {

      /* Re-use an existing buffer */

      /* Get the oldest buffer */
      jbuf = bf->ibuf_oldest;
      /* Delete oldest buffer from old/new pointer list */
      p = bf->bstat[jbuf].buf_p;
      bf->ibuf_oldest = bf->bstat[jbuf].newer;
      bf->bstat[bf->ibuf_oldest].older = -1;

      bf->bstat[jbuf].buf_p = NULL;
      bf->bstat[jbuf].older = -1;
      bf->bstat[jbuf].newer = -1;
      bf->bstat[jbuf].initialized = 1;

    }

    /* Put current buffer in old/new pointer list */
    bf->bstat[ibuf].loc = MEM_ONLY;
    bf->bstat[ibuf].buf_p = p;
    bf->bstat[ibuf].older = bf->ibuf_newest;
    bf->bstat[ibuf].newer = -1;
    bf->bstat[ibuf].initialized = 1;

    bf->ibuf_end = ibuf;
    bf->bstat[bf->ibuf_newest].newer = ibuf;
    bf->ibuf_newest = ibuf;

  }

  /* Calculate pointer to memory location of element */
  p = (unsigned char *) bf->bstat[ibuf].buf_p + (jelm * bf->elm_size);

  return p;
}


int 
Buf_Close( Buf_bf_p bf )
/*******************************************************************************
!C
!Description: Buf_Close (buffer cache file close) writes the remainder of the 
 cache to the disk cache file and closes the file and frees memory of the 
 buffer data structure and buffers.

!Input Parameters:
 bf     pointer to the buffer data structure 

 Notes:
   1. 'Buf_Create' or 'Buf_Open' must be called before this routine to open
      the file.

!END
*****************************************************************************/
{
  int i;
  long dsk_loc;
  logical_t cmplt_flag;
  /* int b; */
  Buf_elm_p p;
  long ibuf, nelm_wrt;
  int  nb;
  unsigned char header[HEADER_SIZE];

  /* Write remaining buffers which are still only in memory */
  for (ibuf = 0; ibuf < (bf->ibuf_end + 1); ibuf++)
  /* for (ibuf = 0; ibuf < (bf->ibuf_end); ibuf++)*/{
    p = bf->bstat[ibuf].buf_p;
    /* Free the buffer memory */
**THIS FOLLOWING LINE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS COMING FROM**

**VALGRIND SHOWS `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` ERROR**

**BUT AM NOT SURE HOW `p` is coming out to be uninitialized`**

if (p != NULL) free(p);  
}

  /* Free the buffer status memory */
  free(bf->bstat);

  /* Free the buffer cache data structure */
  bf->fp = (FILE *)NULL;
  bf->key = 0;
  free(bf);  

  printf("buf here 5\n");
  return BUF_NORMAL;
}
```

Comment: If it works fine on a 32 bit machine and not on a 64 bit machine, the problem is probably in your code and certainly not in the glibc. Did you run it with valgrind on 32 bits ? Or maybe you have a problem with pointer arithmetic somewhere (assuming that pointers are 32 bits wide) ?

Comment: Yeah I know the problem is somewhere in the itself and not in glibc. This code was originally meant for 32 bit machine and my feeling is there is some 64 bit specific changes that may have to be made which i am not sure of.

Answer (score 3):

I work on a project that has a lot of questionable practices (currently working toward cleaning them up).  I ran into this error and went through everything I could imagine to ferret out where the problem was including clang sanitizers, a variety of valgrind tools, and a variety of other tricks.

The problem: exit() was being called in one thread about the same time as `main()` returned, so all the global/static constructors were being kicked off in two separate threads simultaneously.  I'm actually kind of annoyed I didn't make the connection sooner.

This error also manifests as:

- `double free or corruption`

  - ... which may also be caused by [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984290/crash-when-destructors-for-static-objects-are-executing/40984291?noredirect=1#comment69178353_40984291)
- segfault/sig11 inside `exit()`
- Crashes inside `malloc_consolidate` with a call stack that looks like:

I guess you can't add code examples after a bullet item

```
#0  0xabcdabcd in malloc_consolidate () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0xabcdabcd in _int_free () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0xabcdabcd in operator delete (...)
#3  0xabcdabcd in operator delete[] (...)
(...)
```

Furthermore, I couldn't get it to exhibit this problem while running under valgrind -- whether it was a timing issue, or some artifact of how valgrind works that hid the problem I may never know.

Answer (score 0):

It bit difficult to understand your program logic by static analysis. However Valgrind print "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value" under the scenario
where program attempts to make use of uninitialized data in a way that might affect your program's externally-visible behaviour.
Sources of uninitialised data tend to be:

1. Local variables in procedures which have not been initialized.
2. The contents of heap blocks (allocated with malloc, new, or a similar function) before you (or a constructor) write something there.

To see information on the sources of uninitialised data in your program, you may use 
the option **--track-origins=yes**. So You can run the program(./a.out) as follows:

> valgrind --tool=memcheck --track-origins=yes ./a.out

This might be helpful and provide more useful information closer to your actual source of your problem.You can find more detailed information about it from the location:

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html

Comment: You can also change the malloc() with calloc() in the module where valgrind is reporting the error and may verify it once. Even though the most of the places memset() has been called after malloc(), however it might be some corner case where memset() is not getting called contents may be uninitialized which might lead to this scenario.

Comment: I did ran Valgrind with `--track-origin=yes` but that output is still not very helpful. Also how will using `calloc` instead of `malloc` help here? This is the issue of somehow the pointer remaining unitialized. Whether you use malloc or calloc the pointer should get initialized at least with the proper address to a newly allocated space. Use of calloc will only fill all the allocated space with zero.

Comment: If your logic is such that you would be allocating the memory and then store(the base address) into the another memory which is on heap.Now if by some means if your first allocation does not happen and another memory still goes and try to free that memory, then this problem may encountered. So if you use calloc() then even you do not do the first call of allocation, you would be safe as the !null check would be failed at the time of freeing the memory using the stored address on the 2nd heap memory.

Comment: can you kindly elaborate on this a little bit maybe with a small example. Maybe I am not aware of this difference between calloc and malloc and maybe this is my answer.

Comment: @srsci, I have explained this with example with appropriate comments. You can check out the code from the location https://github.com/mantosh4u/mkrdscpp/blob/master/stackoverflow/example.c